# How to use a poncho in high winds?

Tags: clothing, wind

Are there any recommendations about how to use a poncho to get shelter from the wind?

I was thinking about wrapping some cord around my waist to hold it in place, but maybe there are better options (that don't require any extra item for instance, or more effective ones).

Comment: Possibility of high winds is high up on my check list for when not to take a poncho.

Comment: Agreed. But, I wanted to know how to mitigate the issue in case it happens.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen people wear ponchos with a belt around the midriff, it looks cool. Ultimately it's probably not the best garment in high wind.

You could try sewing in elastic draw cords.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on canoe trips.  I would wear my life jacket over my poncho.  Worked a treat.

One of the things in my backpack is a bungie cord long enough to use as a belt.  It has a bunch of uses in camp too, but fastening around a poncho works.

One other easy mod for ponchos is to add some snaps or velcro tabs to make sleeves.

Another thing I did with one poncho was to wrap it around me, and at waist level put gromets in the hem.  This allowed a short chunk of parachute cord to link them together.